# Call view from function of controller

Tags: php, laravel

Here are two versions of TestController, I think they are same, TestController calls the welcome.blade.php file.

As a result of this code, 'welcome' view is shown.

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
public function first($status)
{        
    if($status==0)
    return view::make('welcome');
} 
}
```

But this code creates only a blank page.Why this happens?

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
public function test()
{
    return view::make('welcome');
}
public function first($status)
{        
    if($status==0)
  $this->test();
} 
}
```

Comment: `return $this->test();` in `first` function

Answer (score 0):

You should return view from controller method:

```
public function first($status)
{        
    if ($status === 0)
        return $this->test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now create  errorexception                                                                      Use of undefined constant test - assumed 'test'

Comment: @AlimurRaziRana check if you copied code correctly.